# How to convert LPTSTR to LPCWSTR?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, winapi, msdn

I need to convert from `LPTSTR` to `LPCWSTR`.
I need this because I'm getting `LPTSTR` from `GetDlgItemText`, which I'm going to feed to `ExtTextOut`, which accepts `LPCWSTR`.

Edit:
Before passing of the value from `GetDlgItemText` I store the value in `std::vector`. After which I retrieve the value from the `std::vector` and it returns me an empty/giberish.

**Dialog box:**

```
WORD lineLength = (WORD) SendDlgItemMessage(hwnd,IDC_EDIT1, EM_LINELENGTH, (WPARAM) 0, (LPARAM) 0);
if(lineLength > 0){
    TCHAR line[16];
    int number = GetDlgItemTextW(hwnd, IDC_EDIT1, line, 16);
    HWND parent = (HWND)GetWindowLongPtr(hwnd, GWLP_HWNDPARENT);
    LPCWSTR line2(line);
    SendMessage(parent, WM_COMMAND, MAKEWPARAM(ADD_COMBO_ITEM,0), (LPARAM)line);
```

It sends a message to the parent window, which adds this value to the vector (**`push_back`**).
The class with the parentwindow:

```
std::vector<LPCWSTR> comboItems
```

this is a piece of a function that I use to output my values using **`ExtTextOut`**:

```
RECT temp;
temp.left = listItemWidth;
temp.right = width;
SetBkColor(hdc, RGB(240,240,260));
LPCWSTR comboName = L"";
for(std::vector<item>::size_type i=0; i != comboItems.size(); i++){
temp.left = listItemWidth;
    temp.right = width;
    temp.top = (currentlyClicked + 1) * listItemHeight + i * listItemHeight;
    temp.bottom = temp.top + listItemHeight;
    comboName = comboItems[i];
    ExtTextOut(hdc, temp.left+2, temp.top + 1, ETO_OPAQUE, 
                &temp, comboName, lstrlen(comboName), 0);
    DrawEdge(hdc, &temp, EDGE_RAISED, BF_RECT | BF_FLAT | BF_ADJUST);
}
```

Comment: Take a good look at the [MSDN Library article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162713(v=vs.85).aspx) for ExtTextOut.  And show us where it says it accepts LPCWSTR.  You don't have to convert.

Comment: I'm facing the problem, before passing the value from EditBox(GetDltItemText) I store the value in std::vector, and then upon using ExtTextOut I call for this value from the vector.

Comment: std::vector is not a great string type.  Use std::wstring.

Comment: `std::vector` creates a mutable array, which I can populate with any data that I want. While `std::wstring` is a wide char string.

Comment: Except that the data you want to populate it with is character data. We have a special name for that type of array, it's called a string. You should still be using std::wstring.

Comment: Didn't know that, I thought you can use std::vector for everything

Answer (score 3):

`GetDlgItemText` has support for both, and so does `ExtTextOut`. Are these calls in two different projects? Or do you have `#define UNICODE` somewhere? In any case, I would recommend either:

- Fix the projects or source files so they both use the wide character or the multibyte version, but not both, OR
- Expicitly call `GetDlgItemTextW` or `ExtTextOutA`.

Your data is being corrupted because you are only pushing a pointer into the vector. This pointer points to a stack variable which is long gone by the time you access the pointer. You should store `std::wstring` in your vector.

Comment: No, they are both called in the same project. The thing is that the value is getting lost on the way. I think it's a conversion problem. Because before storing of the value in the vector, I check it with messagebox and it displays the right value, though when I retrieve it from the std::vector it is sometimes empty, giberish, dots etc.

Comment: That means you're not managing your memory properly. Show your code.

Comment: I've added the code, Though I've tried passing normal strings using "L", and it worked.

Comment: Please see the additional notes regarding the corruption problem.

Comment: Yes, storing pointers to invalid data is the real problem. The suggestion has been made several times now to use `std::wstring`. For some reason, the asker is resisting this advice.

Comment: No, I'm not :D, I've decided to stick with std::wstring, thanks all for the help

Answer (score 2):

This can be done via [`MultiByteToWideChar`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd319072%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: or without.. depending on what LPTSTR actually is depending on config.

Answer (score -1):

CStringW s( your_LPTSTR );

then you can have it by implicit conversion.

Comment: There is no evidence that he's using ATL or MFC, so the `CString` class is not available. And there's absolutely no reason to prefer it over `std::wstring`.

Comment: @Cody: of course there is, including that wstring does NOT construct from both narrow and wide string, thus making it config-agnostic